# How to access Microsoft Edge browser and login into website via VBA

Tags: vba, authentication, browser, microsoft-edge

I'm currently trying to add to an existing macro that I'm working on. I'm trying to access a website, run a query, download the document and open it via VBA. The catch is I have to use Microsoft Edge as the browser, I cannot use Internet Explorer. I've tried what feels like a million different ways, and nothing seems to work. I know I need to reference the sites HTML code to accomplish the login, but I haven't been able to navigate to the edge browser.

I had a colleague send me a large file with numerous class modules he'd created which allowed him to access edge and login to said site, but I've had a hard time trying to duplicate this. Any advice?

Comment: Have you look at using Selenium from VBA to automate Edge?  Eg see https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/answers/questions/843285/edge-opening-and-filling-a-webpage-through-vba

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.